# Preserving jquery mobile styles when meteor js elements/fields update

Tags: jquery-mobile, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor project at the moment that utilises Meteor JS & jQuery Mobile. All is going well apart from certain circumstances where Meteor updates an element.

For example, JQM automagically adds a few surrounding divs to a select box for formatting purposes (`.ui-select`, `.ui-btn`, `.ui-shadow`, etc.) but when Meteor updates this element, whether from a remote or local db change, it reverts the element to a standard select box, in effect ruining the UI.

I was just wondering if there is a easy solution to this issue where Meteor calls on jQuery to make changes prior to updating the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically added **`jQuery Mobile`** content must be enhanced.

It can be done in few ways, but most common ones are:

1. In case you want to enhance only content

   ```
   $('#page-id').trigger('create');
   ```
2. In case you want to enhance full page (content + header + footer)

   ```
   $('#page-id').trigger('pagecreate');
   ```

It is good to know that these method are performance extensive so you can always enhance widgets (buttons, listviews ...) separately. To find out more take a look at my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Comment: I've stumbled across this when looking for a solution to refreshing JQM listviews so that the styles are reapplied. Within meteor, I need to wait for listview to render and be visible before I can refresh and `Meteor.template.rendered` is not late enough (listview has no li's yet). Do you know where I can do that from within Meteor? The only solution I've found to date is to use `Meteor.timeout()` and wait about 200ms for it populate the listview's li's, then I can refresh.  Any ideas for an event driven solution?